# Text fade-in with Transition Manager not working with RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-transitions

I have a fragment holding a recyclerview, and when I tap on an item I want the textviews within it to fade out for a scene transition into an Activity. When I hit the back button to go back to the fragment, the text in the recyclerview item should fade back in. The problem is that this only works for the first item in the recyclerview. For any other item, the text fades out but stays invisible when I move back to the fragment.

toggleVisibility method call in the Adapter's onBindViewHolder:

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String imageTransitionName = context.getString(R.string.timeline_item_transition_image);

                Pair imagePair = new Pair<>(view.findViewById(R.id.timeline_image_framelayout), imageTransitionName);

                ActivityOptionsCompat optionsCompat =
                        ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(mUpcomingEventsFragment.getActivity(),
                        imagePair);
                toggleVisibility(holder.itemView, false);

                view.getContext().startActivity(EventDetailActivity.newIntent(context,
                        (Event) mTimelineItemList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition())), optionsCompat.toBundle());

            }
        });
```

And the method with the TransitionManager's fade:

```
public void toggleVisibility(View view, boolean visible) {
    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition((ViewGroup) view, new Fade());
    TextView timeText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.event_time);
    TextView titleText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.event_title);
    timeText.setVisibility(visible ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
    titleText.setVisibility(visible ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

I am calling the `toggleVisibility` method when the fragment resumes, `mUpcomingEventsAdapter.toggleVisibility(mRecyclerView, true);`
  but my problem is that I'm just not sure how to set the visibility correctly on the selected item from the recyclerview when I go back to the fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Recycler View contains multiple views which all have the same ids on their text views (The recycler view reuses the view on each item). Thats why it only changes one views visibility, when you try to change it.

You could do something like this:

Add a toggleAllVisibilities method to your adapter:

```
public void toggleAllVisibilities(boolean visible) {
    this.visible = visible;
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

The method notifyDatasetChanged() tells the recyclerview-Adapter, that the containing data changed and it should recall onBindViewHolder for each item.
visible should be a global variable in your adapter.

Now you could set in onBindViewholder the visibility of each item with your original toggleVisibility method.
toggleVisibility(holder.itemView, visible);

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a good solution. What I eventually ended up doing is adding a public getPosition() method in the adapter in order to get the position from onBindViewHolder. That way in the fragment I can toggle the visibility on the ViewHolder with the method I already had by using recyclerview.getLayoutManager().findViewByPosition(int position). Not sure if this is too expensive or not though, so I will also give your suggestion a shot to see what runs best. Thanks again!